# Preventing URL variable to do not show in the url

Tags: php

i m trying to pass a record  for updation  to another page by passing the id of the record and i want to do not show the id in the URL like Update-record.php?id=23

Answer (score 0):

few options like:
1) instead of passing in url post the data.
2) encode while passing through url and decode while updating

Comment: u mean pass the data through POST method ??

Comment: Update-record.php?id=23 but this is a URL variable how can i post it'

Comment: Have a form in your page and update "id" in that form and then submit using JS

Comment: I m sending the information from a table where I have shown the records

Answer (score 0):

you can do that

1.using post method

2.use encode your get param

3.use nginx rewrite url to -> `update-record/1`

Answer (score -1):

If you are using
    `form method="GET"`
change it to
    `form method = "POST"`